# How to change new to malloc?

Tags: c++, c

I am changing my language from c++ to c and want to use new, however, c doesn't allow the use of new, so i have to use malloc.

```
malloc(sizeof(*ThreadNum))
```

the line above does not work when i tried to do it myself and have run out of options. This is the line that i wish to switch. Any tips would be lovely:)

```
for(i=0; i <NUM_THREADS; i++){

ThreadS [i] = new struct ThreadNum; //allocating memory in heap
(*ThreadS[i]).num = num;
(*ThreadS[i]).NumThreads = i;
pthread_t ID;

printf("Creating thread %d\n", i); //prints out when the threads are created

rc = pthread_create(&ID, NULL, print, (void *) ThreadS[i]); //creates the threads
```

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(struct ThreadNum))`

Comment: Wrong question. Right question would be how to change owning raw pointers to smart pointers.

Comment: Do i have to edit this line now?  NewData = (ThreadNum *)threadid; in a separate void  function?

Comment: @Swordfish It's the opposite, right? This question wants to go from c++ to c.

Comment: @Jake, don't cast it. In c you don't neet to cast `void *`. It's the most famous question and answer on SO for the [tag:c] tag.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Oh. A ... unique ... decision.

Comment: Style note: `ThreadS[i]->num = num;` is easier to read.

Comment: @Swordfish It's a matter of taste. C++ is becoming both, horrible and popular. Like every other popular language, it's ugly. I personally prefer to write c code a lot. It's simpler and programs are elegant. It's also less to remember and more to create.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I've got the impression that C++ becomes more and more \*un\*popular. But gains beautifulness with every revision of the standard.

Answer (score 7):

First thing you need to consider is that `new` and `malloc()` are not equivalents. Second thing is that `ThreadNum` is a `struct` so you may want to write `sizeof(struct ThreadNum)` but usually a better choice is like this

```
ThreadNum *thread_num = malloc(sizeof(*thread_num));
```

note that above `thread_num` is not a type or `struct`, it's a variable and has pointer type. Using `*` before it means that you want the size of the type with one less level of indirection.

Getting back to my first comment, `new` does not only allocate memory but it also invokes the object constructor, which is something that does not exist in [c](/questions/tagged/c).

In c you have to do all the initialization by hand and after checking that `malloc()` did return a valid pointer.